# Pod can't access kubelet endpoints

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, cadvisor

When ever my pods try to query any kubelet endpoints (any port), they immediately get a `connection refused`.

My goal is to have prometheus get those metrics from cadvisor, and I am trying to create a ServiceMonitor to scrape the cadvisor metrics (for info on pod level resource usage).

Trying `wget` from any pod on my cluster results in the following:

```
$ wget 10.116.0.10:4194
Connecting to 10.116.0.10:4194 (10.116.0.10:4194)
wget: can't connect to remote host (10.116.0.10): Connection refused
```

I am running on DigitalOcean managed Kubernetes

edit: the above happens on any port, not just 4194

ServiceMonitor:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: kubelet
  labels:
    app: prometheus
spec:
  jobLabel: k8s-app
  endpoints:
  - port: cadvisor
    interval: 15s
    honorLabels: true
    tlsConfig:
      insecureSkipVerify: true
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: kubelet
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: prometheus-operator
      app.kubernetes.io/name: kubelet
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - kube-system
```

Comment: On Kubernetes, cAdvisor is inside kubelet binary, as you should know. So you can install `metrics-server` and just scrap the data directly from kubernetes API as Prometheus was intended to do.

Comment: @HectorVido I would love to scrape `metrics-server`, but it is not in Prometheus format, nor does it list all of the metrics on a single endpoint.

Comment: When using [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack), scraping kubelet cadvisor metrics should be [enabled by default](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L763-L767). If you are not using promethus stack you can still use [kubelet/servicemonitor.yaml](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/templates/exporters/kubelet/servicemonitor.yaml) and see how its done. Is it any helpful information?

Comment: @Matt I've been trying to decipher the helm file. I'm not using helm in the install so I need to convert that to a normal ServiceMonitor but I will try!

Comment: @Matt Something I had done following that must have been it, maybe a different port or using the right TLS config or both but it works now!

Answer (score 0):

The error "Connection refused" indicates a firewall could block the port or no service is listening on the port. Are you sure using the right port?

The port `4194` is the port used by cAdvisor, why would you like to access it with an IP (10.116.0.10)? It has nothing related to Kubelet.

Comment: I've added my ServiceMonitor above. It seems thats that it decides to use that IP, which happens to be the private IP of the node. In the `Targets` tab everything is hitting some IP. I am sure it is the right port, and I can access the endpoint from `kubectl` on my laptop.

Comment: Not the private IP of the node, but of the endpoint listed in `kubectl get endpoints` rather